# Finding the sum of minimum distance from the points in one list to points in other list?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have two lists containing x and y number of n-dimensional points respectively. I had to calculate the sum of minimum distances of each point in list one (containing x points) from each point in second list (containing y points). The distance I am calculating is Euclidean distance. The optimized solution is needed.

I have already implemented its naive solution in Python. But its time complexity is too much to be used anywhere. There will be optimization possible. Can this problems time complexity be reduced than what I have implemented?

I was reading this[paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf) which I was trying to implement. In this they were having the similar problem to which they stated that it's special condition of [Earth Mover Distance](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/RUBNER/emd.htm). As there was no code given, hence unable to know how it got implemented. Thus my naive implementation, the above code was too slow to work on data set of 11k documents. I used Google Colab for executing my code.

```py
# Calculating Euclidean distance between two points
def euclidean_dist(x,y):
  dd = 0.0
  #len(x) is number of dimensions. Basically x and y is a 
  #list which contains coordinates of a point
  for i in range(len(x)):
    dd = dd+(x[i]-y[i])**2
  return dd**(1/2)

# Calculating the desired solution to our problem
def dist(l1,l2):
  min_dd = 0.0
  dd = euclidean_dist(l1[0],l2[0])
  for j in range(len(l1)):
    for k in range(len(l2)):
      temp = euclidean_dist(l1[j],l2[k])
      if dd > temp:
        dd = temp
    min_dd = min_dd+dd
    dd = euclidean_dist(l1[j],l2[0])
  return min_dd
```

Comment: Do you have some information indicating that a much faster solution exists? Note that you can reduce the number of costly `sqrt` operations by avoiding it in the  `euclidian_dist` function, and just calling it when calculating the final sum

Comment: I was reading this [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf). In this they were having the similar problem to which they stated that it's special condition of [Earth Mover Distance](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/RUBNER/emd.htm). As there was no code given, hence unable to know how it got implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the distance between two points, you can use the distance formula:

[image]

which you can implement like that in python:

```
import math

def dist(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt(pow(x1 - x2, 2) + pow(y1 - y2, 2))
```

Then all you need to do is to loop over X or Y list, check the distance of two points and store it if it's under the current stored minimal distance. You should end up with a O(n²) complexity algorithm which is what you seems to want. Here a working example:

```
min_dd = None
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(l1)):
        dd = dist(l1[i], l2[i], l1[j], l2[j])
        if min_dd is None or dd < min_dd:
            min_dd = dd
```

With this you can get pretty good performances even with large list of points.

Comment: The points are n-dimensional. Secondly, if you look into my code, the approach is same.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce runtime, I would suggest finding manhattan distances (delta x + delta y), sorting the resulting array for each point and then creating a buffer of +20% of lowest manhattan distance, if values in the sorted list are in that range of +20%, you can  compute euclidean distances and find the correct/minimum euclidean answer.

This will reduce some time, but the 20% figure might not reduce time if the points are all close together as most of them will fit in the buffer region, try fine-tuning the 20% parameter to see what works best for your dataset. Keep in mind reducing it too much might lead to inaccurate answers due to the nature of euclidean vs. manhattan distances.

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to a k-nearest-neighbor problem so finding each closest point to a given point cost O(N) and for your problem should be O(N^2).

Sometimes Using [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) MAY improve some performance if your data is low-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

## Small arrays

For two numpy arrays `x` and `y` of shape `(n,)` and `(m,)` respectively, you can vectorize the distance calculations and then get the minimum distance:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
m = 20

x = np.random.random(n)
y = np.random.random(m)

# Using squared distance matrix and taking the
# square root at the minimum value
distance_matrix = (x[:,None]-y[None,:])**2
minimum_distance_sum = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.min(distance_matrix, axis=1)))
```

For arrays of shape `(n,l)` and `(m,l)`, you just need to calculate the `distance_matrix` as:

```
distance_matrix = np.sum((x[:,None]-y[None,:])**2, axis=2)
```

Alternatively, you could use `np.linalg.norm`, `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`, `np.einsum` etc., but in many cases they are not faster.

## Large arrays

If `l`, `n` and `m` above are too large for you to keep the distance_matrix in memory, you can use the mathematical lower and upper bound of the euclidean distance to increase the speed (see [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7860222). Since this relies on for loops, it will be very slow, but one can wrap the functions with numba to counter this:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def get_squared_distance(a,b):
    return np.sum((a-b)**2)

def get_minimum_distance_sum(x,y):
    n = x.shape[0]
    m = y.shape[0]
    l = x.shape[1]

    # Calculate mean and standard deviation of both arrays
    mx = np.mean(x, axis=1)
    my = np.mean(y, axis=1)
    sx = np.std(x, axis=1)
    sy = np.std(y, axis=1)
    return _get_minimum_distance_sum(x,y,n,m,l,mx,my,sx,sy)

@numba.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def _get_minimum_distance_sum(x,y,n,m,l,mx,my,sx,sy):
    min_distance_sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        min_distance = get_squared_distance(x[i], y[0])
        for j in range(1,m):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                continue
            lower_bound = l * ((mx[i] - my[j])**2 + (sx[i] - sy[j])**2)
            if lower_bound >= min_distance:
                continue
            distance = get_squared_distance(x[i], y[j])
            if distance < min_distance:
                min_distance = distance
        min_distance_sum += np.sqrt(min_distance)

    return min_distance_sum

def test_minimum_distance_sum():
    # Will likely be much larger for this to be faster than the other method
    n = 10
    m = 20
    l = 100

    x = np.random.random((n,l))
    y = np.random.random((m,l))

    return get_minimum_distance_sum(x,y)
```

This approach should be faster than the former approach with increased array size. The algorithm can be improved slightly as described in the paper, but any speedup would depend heavily on the shape of the arrays.

## Timings

On my laptop, on two arrays of shape `(1000,100)`, your approach takes ~1 min, the "small arrays" approach takes 690 ms and the "large arrays" approach takes 288 ms. For two arrays of shape `(100, 3)`, your approach takes 28 ms, the "small arrays" approach takes 429 μs and the "large arrays" approach takes 578 μs.